# Odoo : make form fields show/hide based on dropdown

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

My custom module view looks like this

```
<odoo>
    <data>

         <record model="ir.ui.view" id="session_form_view">
            <field name="name">item.form</field>
            <field name="model">inventory.item</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Items Form">
                    <sheet>
                        <group>
                            <field name="name"/>
                            <field name="code"/>
                            <field name="department"/>
                            <field name="state"/>
                        </group>

                        <group>
                            <field name="measurement"  position="attributes">
                                <attribute name="attrs">{'invisible': [('state', '=', True)]}</attribute>
                            </field>
                        </group>
                    </sheet>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>

        <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="items_tree">
            <field name="name">Item</field>
            <field name="res_model">inventory.item</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
            <!-- <field name="context" eval="{'state':True}" /> -->
        </record>


        <menuitem id="main_openacademy_menu" name="Inventory"></menuitem>
        <menuitem id="openacademy_menu" name="Store" parent="main_openacademy_menu"></menuitem>
        <menuitem id="store_items_menu" name="Store items" parent="openacademy_menu" action="items_tree"/>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

I have a simple model

I want to hide/show based on the department drop down. But some how for a lot of cases attrs is not working.  I am begginer and using odoo 10. 
Thanks

Comment: I can't see the attrs on any field which is hide/show on department dropdown.

Comment: It's found as a child in measurement field

Comment: Yes. but in that you checked for the state not for department.